# Storing multiple radio buttons values using angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to use multiple radio buttons.there are 10 questions with each question having a unique id and each question have 5 options with each option having unique id.I want to store selected values using formcontrolname. what is the best approach ??

the questions and options format is
questions:

```
[
  {
    id: 1
    title: "questiontitle1"
    options: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "optionname1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "optionname2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2
    title: "questiontitle2"
    options: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "optionname1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "optionname2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

html code is

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Form Array](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray).

A FormArray is responsible for managing a collection of AbstractControl, which can be a FormGroup, a FormControl, or another FormArray.

A great [tutorial](https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a) to follow step by step.

Comment: can we store radio button values with formarray can you share code please